# SQL: how to get global overview of database

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am new SQL and I was wondering if there is any quick way of getting a global "view" of a new database (if for example you are starting to use a database you know nothing about and you want to just get a global idea of how the entire database looks like).

In other words is there a way to :

1. Maybe get some graphical representation of the database? - a sort of diagram that shows the relation between all tables
2. Maybe do some sort of query that could return the no. of rows, no. columns (and ideally column names) of each table in the database?

Apologies if this is a really basic question, I am very new to SQL. I am currently using PostgreSQL and PgAdmin4. Thanks

Comment: One approach would be to search online for tools that create ERD from your database, or inspect your tables one by one and draw your own looking at foreign keys.

Comment: There are tools which can create graphical data model from your entire database. But from my experience I can tell they are useful only for small amount of tables. Complicated graphical data models are usually quite useless. They are simply too complicated to give you any useful info. I would suggest - try to break down the whole model to partial models around some most important tables and study these parts first. As for row counts in PostgreSQL look into table pg_stat_all_tables, column "n_live_tuples".

Comment: For number 2, you could query `information_schema.columns`, something like: `SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position`